# Is it possible to modify an existing AWS implementation of a deep learning model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deep-learning, image-segmentation, amazon-sagemaker

I wish to modify an existing model implementation in order to add an additional upsampling layer to a [semantic segmentation algorithm that has previously been implemented in AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/semantic-segmentation.html).

It appears that Sagemaker refers to [this repo](https://github.com/dmlc/gluon-cv/tree/4e1d44d718ca998523527aa2039cde2184d31296), and I'm hoping to modify [the deeplab model](https://github.com/dmlc/gluon-cv/blob/4e1d44d718ca998523527aa2039cde2184d31296/gluoncv/model_zoo/deeplabv3.py) to add a final additional upsampling layer that is higher resolution than the initial input layer in order to boost the resolution of the output image (i.e., statistically downscale the original imagery).

([This technique has been demonstrated with UNET architectures.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349804789_A_Deep_Learning_Approach_to_Downscale_Geostationary_Satellite_Imagery_for_Decision_Support_in_High_Impact_Wildfires))

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker built-in algos are designed to be used with SageMaker prebuilt algo containers.

If you would like to have full flexibility on the architecture I would suggest building and training your own model using one of the Frameworks such as [MXNet](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/mxnet/using_mxnet.html).